# node.js mongodb find() results to array but not use .filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript

I trying to use `Array.filter()` on result returned from `mongodb.find()`, 
but it's not working!
 I am getting this error:

> (TS) Property 'filter' does not exist on type '{}'.

```
function find(collectionName: string, filter: any = {},callback: Function) {
    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    let url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test";

    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
            //throw err;
            db.close();
        } else {
            let rs = db.collection(collectionName).find(filter, { _id: false });

           rs.toArray(function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                callback(null,  result);
                db.close();
            });               

        }

    });//MongoClient

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your code, that you use asynchronous function, as a regular function, which returns a result. Async function returns a promise, or accept callback, which is calling when async operation is finished. Callbacks are produces callback hell, so it's much better use promises or `async/await` feature, added in ES7.

The fixed code, could looks so:

```
function find(collectionName: string, filter: any = {}) {
    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    let url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test";

    return MongoClient
      .connect(url)
      .then(db => db.collection(collectionName).find(filter, { _id: false }))
      .then(rs => rs.toArray())
      .finally(() => db.close());
}
```

One note, currently, `find` function doesn't accept `callback` parameter, it returns a promise, so to use result in calling code, you should create a promise chain:

```
find(...)
  .then(results => // TODO: use results here)
  .catch(err => // TODO: process error here);
```